# Spring UriTemplateHandler.expand not encoding plus (+) symbol

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using OpenAPI's generator to create a Spring `RestTemplate` client.
It uses the following snippet to produce the final URI from query parameters.

```java
restTemplate.getUriTemplateHandler().expand(pathTemplate, variables)
```

This has problems when the parameter value contains the plus `+` symbol because it does not encode the `+` into `%2B` but when provided with `%2B`, it double encodes the `%` symbol, so it's also wrong. This looks like a bug. Is there a way to override this without an upstream fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this by adding an EncodingMode to your UriTemplateHandler.  When you're constructing your RestTemplate bean, you can add the encoder there.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    DefaultUriBuilderFactory builderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
    builderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY);

    return new RestTemplateBuilder().uriTemplateHandler(builderFactory).build();
}
```